# Mapping a sql view to a php entity with doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a view in my database created with

```
CREATE VIEW TBL_TITLE (...)
```

That view is described in yaml by

```
HQ\Title:
  type: entity
  table: TBL_TITLE
  fields:
    (...)
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

This works fine: my entities are loaded and written correctly. But when I run `orm:schema-tool:update`, I get

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_TITLE (...);
```

So doctrine2 (2.1.6) doesn't see that `TBL_TITLE` already exists as a view and wants to create a table. How can I declare `TBL_TITLE` as a view so that schema-tool recognize it?

Comment: To clarify why I care: I'm using doctrine migrations, and every migrations:diff reports these "create table" and we have to remember to ignore them every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot, the schema tool isn't able to handle that at current state.

Comment: @Keyne no link, I'm just reading through https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php#L148 and it explicitly requires tables.